# Using Rtsp with Netty and Websockets

Tags: java, websocket, netty, nio, rtsp

For my bachelor thesis I'm currently developing a content streaming system using Netty as the server and a javascript application with websockets in the browser. For the control of streaming I'm going to use the rtsp protocol.

Netty offers support for rtsp but I couldn't find much information about rtsp and Netty at all. Is it possible to use the Netty rtsp implementation with the Netty websocket implementation directly? Or do I have to write my own implementation for the rtsp protocol, which runs over the websocket layer?

Thank you for any information or examples for this scenario.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried already? Can you post any examples you've tried?

Comment: Currently I work with code based on the example from chapter 11 from the meap version of netty in action:
[netty in action - chapter 11](https://github.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action/tree/master/src/main/java/com/manning/nettyinaction/chapter11)  
I couldn't figure out how to integrate netty rtsp implementation with websockets in anyway.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... So you want to run RTSP over the websocket connection ?

Comment: Thank you Norman. Yes I want to run RTSP over the websocket connection for my application. But unfortunatly I couldn't find out how to acomplish this with the RTSP implementation of Netty on the server side.